# can we call any method on null object?

Tags: java, null, method-call

is it possible?

```
Object obj=null;

obj.someMethod();

someMethod{/*some code here*/}
```

Comment: Well you certainly *can*... just the method can't be executed as you get a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 9):

You can call a static method on a null pointer. The pointer will naturally be completely ignored in a static method call, but it's still a case when something that (without looking at the class definition) seemingly should cause a NullPointerException runs just fine.

```
class FooObject {
    public static void saySomething() {
        System.out.println("Hi there!");
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FooObject foo = null;
        foo.saySomething();
    }
}
```

But just to make it clear - no, you can't call an instance method with a null pointer. Protecting the programmer against this is one of the really basic protections that set languages like Java apart from "lower level languages" such as C++. It enables the error to be reported at the calling end, instead of it causing an inexplicable segfault/whatnot inside the method itself.

Comment: It should be noted that calling a `static` method from a variable like this is almost universally considered to be bad style: it implies a relation when there is none.

Comment: Why *almost*? You know of any case where it is prefered?

Comment: @aioobe You may want to indicate that it belongs to a variable "nearby" without having to parse that the variable has a specific type where this static class belongs.

Answer (score 5):

***No*** we can't. it will throw NullPointerException as long as the method is not static. If method is static it will run.

Read this: [null : Java Glossary](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/null.html)

Comment: +0: It won't if someMethod() is static.

Comment: @Nirmal, I suggest you try it. See my example. ;)

Answer (score 3):

No.  In Java, null is not an object.

Answer (score 2):

"obj" variable references to no instance on the heap. For that reason you'll get a nullpointerexception at runtime. Even your Java IDE (Eclipse, IDEA) will catch the problem and warns you about this.

Comment: Not for a static method.  It is correct that IDE's frequently flag this.

Answer (score 2):

**yes** you can call if the method is static because static method is bound at compile time and only type of variable is used for static binding not the value of object.

if you try the same for non static method,get ready to catch a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

you cant execute

null.someMethod(); !!!

Comment: Not like that, but `((ClassWithStaticMethod) null).someMethod()` works just fine ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This will always throw a `NullPointerExcpetion` unless someMethod is declared static.  However, calling static methods on an instance is very bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

This won't compile as Object doesn't have `someMethod()`. However if you are talking about something like

```
MyClass o = null;
o.someMethod();
```

the answer depends on whether someMethod is static or not. If it is static, the value is ignored and it doesn't matter if its null or not.

e.g.

```
Thread t = null;
t.yield();
```

runs fine without an exception.

Answer (score 0):

A *null object* does not exist. In your example, you have a variable (a pointer) that can either store a reference to an instance or nothing.

If it doesn't point to an instance - well, then we can't use it to call methods or access fields.

---

*wait, wait* - this compiles and runs:

```
Math m = null;
System.out.println(m.max(1,2));
```

We can call static methods and access static fields in any variable (we just have to ignore compiler/IDE warnings!) **But** that is something different, a static method/variable is not called/accessed on the instance but on the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to call a method on a `null` reference (unless the method is static!). (`null` does not represent some "base" object, it represents a *reference* which does not point to any object at all.)

This works fine however ([ideone.com link](http://ideone.com/pIbUl)):

```
class MethodTest {
    static void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MethodTest mt = null;
        mt.someMethod();
    }
}
```

---

[**Relevant quote from the JLS**](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#45606):

> **15.12.4.4 Locate Method to Invoke**
> The strategy for method lookup depends
>   on the invocation mode.
>
> [...]
>
> **If the invocation mode is `static`**, no target reference is needed and overriding is not allowed. Method `m` of class `T` is the one to be invoked.
>
> Otherwise, an instance method is to be
>   invoked and there is a target
>   reference. **If the target reference is
>   `null`, a `NullPointerException` is thrown
>   at this point.** Otherwise, the target
>   reference is said to refer to a target
>   object and will be used as the value
>   of the keyword `this` in the invoked
>   method.
>
> [...]