# Null can not be compared to double - why?

Tags: java, comparable

To my understanding following code should run fine.

However, When I try to compile, it is failing at `compareTo`

```
public class Test {

    Comparable<?> getMinimum() {
        return null;
    }

    public int getPreviousValue(double nv) {
        return getMinimum().compareTo(nv);
    }
}
```

So my question is why compilation if failing - are we not allowed to compare null with double?

Comment: i think you should use wrapper's Double instead of double.

Comment: Weird, you should be getting a NullPointerException.

Comment: because the double type is a primitive (non-reference) type, and primitive types cannot be null

Comment: Probably because `double` cannot be null, but `Double` (the class) can be. That would be my guess.

Comment: Are we??? Checkout this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090077/how-to-check-if-a-double-is-null

Comment: Your question already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855188/can-we-call-any-method-on-null-object) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java) ;)

Comment: @AniruddhParihar that will not work anyway! using Double results in somthing.getDouble(); which will never assign a null to returned value!

Comment: @W.Seun :  i think it will work! by just changing the signature of Comparable like this : Comparable<Double> getMinimum()

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is **not** the null result of that method.

The problem is that the compiler doesn't know how you could call `compareTo(double)` on something that your `getMinimum()` returns.

You have to change the the signature to `Comparable<Double> getMinimum()` to make it work! You can only compare against a specific type of number if your Comparable supports that!

Of course, at runtime, you will then face a NPE. And also of course: some code inspection tools *could*  identify this specific NPE situation already at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

Compiler is getting confused at `Comparable<?>`. Make the `Comparable` of specific type (`Double` in you case) to make the compiler happy. :)

```
public class Test {

    Comparable<Double> getMinimum() {
        return null;
    }

    public int getPreviousValue(double nv) {
        return getMinimum().compareTo(nv);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a nullpointer, you have a problem invoking compareTo with argument double NOT Double!